# 2D array error: Vector index beyond memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

can someone help me understand why i'm getting this error.

I have a file with numbers
5 4
9 1 5 3
14 12 3 10
9 7 10 14
8 5 0 3
14 13 6 14
8 11

I am adding these numbers to a 2D vector:

```
 25 bool function(const char* myfile){
 26 
 27   std::vector< std::vector<int> > data;
 28 
 29   std::ifstream file(myfile);
 30   std::string line;
 31 
 32   while(std::getline(file, line)){
 33     std::vector<int> lineData;
 34     std::stringstream linestream(line);
 35 
 36     int value;
 37     while(linestream >> value)
 38     {
 39       lineData.push_back(value);
 40     }
 41     data.push_back(lineData);
 42   }
 43 
 44   int i, j = 0;
 45   int vertexSize = 0;
 46   std::vector< std::vector<int> >::iterator row;
 47   std::vector<int>::iterator col;
 48   for( row = data.begin(); row != data.end(); row++, i++){
 49     for(col = row->begin(); col!= row->end(); col++){
 50       std::cout << *col << " ";
 51     }
 52     std::cout << "\n";
 53   }
 54 
 55    vertexSize = data[0][0] * data[0][1];
 56    start = data[i-1][0];
 57    goal = data[i-1][1];
 58 
 59    std::cout << "Vertex Size:" << vertexSize << "\n";
 60    std::cout << "Start: " << start << " goal:" << goal << "\n";
 61   return true;
 62 }
```

When i try to get the last 2 numbers in the last line, i am getting the error:

```
5 4 
9 1 5 3 
14 12 3 10 
9 7 10 14 
8 5 0 3 
14 13 6 14 
8 11 
Vertex Size:20
Start: 8 goal:7
** Vector<T>::operator[] error: vector index beyond memory allocation!
   Unable to recover, no memory allocated
   Terminating program
```

std::cout << data[i-1].size(); Shows 2 elements, which is what I am expecting, yet it is still giving me that index beyond memory allocation error for goal.

It seems that if i go beyond data[number][0], that is when the errors occur.
Can someone explain to me why that is happening?

Thank you for your help.

Debugging with gdb:

```
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x2aaaaaaab000
5 4 
9 1 5 3 
14 12 3 10 
9 7 10 14 
8 5 0 3 
14 13 6 14 
8 11 
0 0
Vertex Size:20
Start: 8 goal:7
** Vector<T>::operator[] error: vector index beyond memory allocation!
   Unable to recover, no memory allocated
   Terminating program

Program exited with code 01.
(gdb) backtrace
No stack.
```

Comment: You're accessing out of bounds of your vector somewhere. However you didn't post the relevant parts of the code. [Please post a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Show the whole output. Also can you explain how the output of `Start:` `Goal:` appears before the index error, it suggests that maybe the error is not in this function at all, e.g. it could be a different vector access that you do afterwards. Use your debugger to find exactly where the vector error is happening.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, start and goal are set to 0. I've added my gdb run in the main post. I'm not sure how else to debug it. My vector use goes to the extent of the function. Once i collect the numbers from the files, i don't use them any longer in anything else.  Thank you for taking the time out to help me btw.

Comment: @12vi6 You start `i` at 0, and I don't see `i` incremented.  But then you do `data[i-1][0]`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am incrementing it on the first for loop, along side the iterator.

    for( row = data.begin(); row != data.end(); row++, i++)
    ...

Comment: @12vi6 ok.  My mistake.  But in any event, make sure that `i` is not 0 when you use `data[i-1]`.  You should also check `data` to ensure it is not empty in both dimensions, regardless of the data that's in the file now.

Comment: That error had to come on some function after the return.  You print successfully, and return `true`, *then* the message appears.  Secondly, to get the last numbers, use `vector::back()` -- This is guaranteed to get you the last item in a vector.  If you're using some sort of "counting" variable to get the last item, drop using it.  Use the guaranteed method, and that is `back()`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie `back` still causes UB if vector is empty, so it's just the same as `i-1` here

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Yes, I'm assuming the vector is not empty, and that the OP may be using some external index variable (which has the incorrect value) to get the last items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that I see is that `i` is not initialized here:

`int i, j = 0;`

You initialized `j`, but not `i`.  So later on when you use `i`, the value is unpredictable.

The solution of course is to do this:

`int i = 0;
 int j = 0;`

But as my comment suggested to you, don't use extraneous variables for counting, or to get the last element in a vector.  If the vector is not empty, then the `vector::back()` function returns a reference to the last item in a vector.